# Проблема включения файла include в php

Tags: php, include

Объясните пожалуйста почему:
если файл вложен в директорию `./papka1/file.php`, то

`include '../db.php';` работает и файл считывается, но

если файл находится в `./papka1/papka2/file.php`, то выводится ошибка:

> Warning: include(../db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

так же и с:

`include './db.php';`

`include 'db.php';`

`include 'http://mysite.com/db.php'`

если вложен в две папки, то на `db.php`, что в корневой, никак не ссылается...

Comment: Чем больше вложенности, тем больше  `../`.  если во второй подпапке файл значит будет `include '../../db.php';`, в третьей - `include '../../../db.php';` и т.д. А вообще правильно когда сайт имеет один корень и оттуда всю подключается

Comment: спасибо, буду знать! :)

Comment: Случай `include "http://..."` очень особенный и вообще-то лучше так не писать никогда! В остальных случаях надо понимать что у нас является *"текущей папкой"* — больше в моём ответе.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Потому, что `..` обозначает предыдущую папку. И если браузер запускает php из с папки вложенной в 2 `/papka1/papka2/file.php` то и текущую, рабочую папку ставит как `/papka1/papka2/`. А `/papka1/papka2/../` - равнозначно `/papka1/`, А ваш db.php лежит видимо уровнем выше. Следовательно включать надо как `include '../../db.php';`

Answer (score -1):

Ответ выше неправильный. Относительный путь нельзя использовать никогда. При любых файловых операциях всегда надо использовать [абсолютный путь](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths).

Если db.php лежит в корне сайта, то писать надо так

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db.php';
```

и это будет работать в любых папках.

Comment: Плохое советуете! $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] работает только в веб-скрипте. И это привяжет приложение к определенному месту относительно DocumentRoot. Нельзя будет систему разместить в под-папке, нельзя будет этот же скрипт вызвать из cron.

Answer (score -1):

`"../"` означает *"на один уровень выше"*. А `"./"` означает *"здесь"*.
Чтобы понять где это, надо разобраться что считается "текущей директорией".

При обращении к php-скрипту через веб-сервер, текущая директория та, где находится "точка входа", т.е. *вызываемый* скрипт.

А при вызове консольного скрипта, текущая директория это та, в которой находится пользователь или системный процесс, *вызывающий* этот скрипт и не зависит от расположения вызываемого php-скрипта.

Если скрипт A инклудит срипт Б, а тот в свою очередь инклудит В и т.д., то в каких бы папках не находились Б и В, текущая папка уже не изменяется. Отсчет идет от одной и той же папки!

Как же быть если мы хотим чтобы скрипт одинаково работал при любом вызове: хоть через веб, хоть из консоли? Нужно использовать абсолютные адреса. Например, можно подставлять константу `__DIR__`, в которой содержится абсолютный адрес папки  данного конкретного срипта.

```
include __DIR__.'/../alfa.php';
include __DIR__.'/subdir/beta.php';
```

Совет Ипатьева годится только для веб-скриптов и к тому же не позволит переместить приложение в какую-нибудь под-папку без правки исходников.